# Last Digits of a power always the same

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $a$ be a number $>2$, $b$ the base and $e>1$ some exponent.
Then it seems that $a^{i\cdot b^e}$ with $i=1,2,3,...$ in base $b=10$ (the number also represented in base 10) always have the same $e+1$ last digits.
It also seems to work in base $b=9$ and $b=8$ (up to the last $e$ digits for some $a$; the $e+1$ digits follows some cycle) but fails for lower bases.
What is the reason behind this?

Comment: In any case, $\varphi (10^n)=4\times 10^{n-1}$ so for any $a$ prime to $10$ your expression is just $1$ mod a high power of $10$.

Comment: But it also works for $a$ not prime e.g. $a=4$ $$                     [1, 6309376]
                    [2, 25509376]
                    [3, 44709376]
                    [4, 63909376]
                    [5, 83109376]
                     [6, 2309376]
                    [7, 21509376]
                    [8, 40709376]
$$

Comment: Nothing to do with $a$ being prime.  I am saying "prime to $10$".  So $a$ is not divisible by $2$ or $5$.  The cases where $a$ is divisible by one of those shouldn't be too hard to work out separately.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. $a=4$ is such a case.

Comment: Sure, for these things it's often easiest to solve it for the relatively prime case (more or less done from my observation) and then analyze the remaining cases separately.  Having finished the relatively prime case you may just as well assume $a=2^m5^n$ and check it for those explicitly.

Comment: These are infinitely many. I presume this observation is true in general...So I need some proof :-/

Comment: Try writing it out!  since $\left( 2^m\right)^k=2^{mk}$.  You may as well take $m=1$ (that already covers all the powers of $2$).  Similarly for $5$.

Comment: Not sure how to write it out :-(
$2^{i\cdot 10^e} = ? \mod 10^d$
?

Comment: Just note that the number $9376$ has the property that all powers of it end in $09376$.  $2^{10^4}$ already ends in $09376$.

Comment: Yes but that is what I want to show. All powers of $2^{10^e}$ have the same last $e+1$ digits.

Comment: Proceed exactly as in the relatively prime case.  Prove that the order of $2\pmod {5^n}$ is $4\times 5^{n-1}$.  Deduce that $2^{10^e}\equiv 1 \pmod {5^{e+1}}$.  That's basically enough (easy to see that the powers of $2$ work out).

Comment: Not sure I follow what you try to tell me but what I have so far is:
\begin{align}
2^{i\cdot 10^e} \mod \underbrace{10^{e+1}}_{2^{e+1}5^{e+1}} &\equiv 2^{e+1} \left(2^{i\cdot 10^{e}-e-1} \mod 5^{e+1} \right) \\
&\equiv 2^{e+1} \left(2^{i\cdot 2^{e-2}\cdot \overbrace{4\cdot 5^{e}}^{\varphi\left(5^{e+1}\right)}-e-1} \mod 5^{e+1} \right) \\
&\equiv 2^{e+1} \left( 2^{-e-1} \mod 5^{e+1} \right)
\end{align}
where $2^{-e-1}$ is understood as the inverse of $2^{e+1} \mod 5^{e+1}$.
Anyway, the result is independent of $i$.

Comment: The congruence symbol is actually an equality.
And I guess all the cases other than $a=2$ work the same.

Comment: Haven't looked into it yet, but I wonder what in these steps goes wrong if I'm choosing a base other than $b=10$. Good night.